# bind, call, apply в чём разница?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно, сабж. Есть информация на английском, но хотелось бы осветить это и для тех, кто английский не знает.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Информация на русском [есть](https://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more), и очень [много](http://habrahabr.ru/post/199456/).

Вкратце:

`call` - вызов функции с подменой контекста - `this` внутри функции. Пример:

```js
function f(arg) {
    alert(arg);
    alert(this);
}

f('abc');             // abc, [object Window]

f.call('123', 'abc'); // abc, 123
```

`apply` - вызов функции с переменным количеством аргументов и с подменой контекста. Пример:

```js
function f() {
    alert(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
}

f(1, 2, 3);                   // [object Window], 1, 2, 3

f.apply('abc', [1, 2, 3, 4]); // abc, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

`bind` - создаёт "обёртку" над функцией, которая подменяет контекст этой функции. Поведение похоже на `call` и `apply`, но, в отличие от них, `bind` не вызывает функцию, а лишь возвращает "обёртку", которую можно вызвать позже. Пример:

```js
function f() {
    alert(this);
}

var wrapped = f.bind('abc');

f();         // [object Window]
wrapped();   // abc
```

Также `bind` умеет подменять не только контекст, но и аргументы функции, осуществляя [каррирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var addOne = add.bind(null, 1);

alert(add(1, 2));   // 3

alert(addOne(2));   // 3
```

Comment: самое путевое и просто объяснение, спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

```
// Создадим простой объект, чтобы использовать его в качестве контекста
var context = { foo: "bar" };

// Функция, которая возвращает свойство «foo» контекста «this»
function returnFoo () {
  return this.foo;
}

// Свойства не существует в текущей области видимости, поэтому undefined
returnFoo(); // => undefined

// Но если мы свяжем эту функцию с контекстом
var bound = returnFoo.bind(context);

// Свойство теперь в области видимости
bound(); // => "bar"

// Существует несколько способов связывания функции с контекстом
// Call и apply позволяют вам вызывать функцию с нужным контекстом
returnFoo.call(context); // => bar
returnFoo.apply(context); // => bar

// Так же можно вложить функцию в объект
context.returnFoo = returnFoo;
context.returnFoo(); // => bar
```